# How to show Graphql errors in the logs?

Tags: graphene-python

I have my website build using below technology stack,

```
Django
GraphQL
Postgres
Nginx
Docker
```

Below is how my docker-compose file looked like,

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  web:
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.prod
    command: gunicorn sports_league.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
    environment:
      - PRODUCTION=true
    env_file:
      - ./config/.env.prod
    expose:
      - 8000
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - web
    volumes:
      - static_volume:/code/staticfiles
      - media_volume:/code/mediafiles
volumes:
  pgdata:
  static_volume:
  media_volume:
```

So when I am running the graphql queries using graphene, only GET / POST request calls show up in the logs.

However, if there is any error, that doesn't show up.

Please advise how can I start to see the error in the logs.